# Why can't I "Add label columns to attribute table" etc. in QGIS 1.9?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Why can't I "Add label columns to attribute table" and why can't I use "Letter spacing", "Word spacing" and so on? I have a shp-file. QGIS version 1.9

[image]

Comment: Same here. Looks like it is not yet implemented.

Comment: That's correct, they are unimplemented at this time. What's enabled is functioning and can be tested. There is currently a larger issue with the data defined functionality of the labeling engine. Once fixed, those options will begin to be worked on in the coming weeks. The 'master' branch is a work under development, not a stable release version. If you have questions about its current state, please ask on the [developer mailing list](http://www.qgis.org/en/community/mailing-lists.html), or download the source code and take a look inside.